# Singleton Referencing

Tags: c#, singleton, pass-by-reference

Okay...I have a situation where a C# .dll is a singleton. Now, what I want to be able to do is when the singletonInstance is instantiated be able to provide a reference to any other applications that may start. So, I looked up NamedPipes and that would work - except for one thing, this must be cross-platform, or platform independent. I have a solution in mind, but I am having a hard time trying to figure out if I can derive a reference to the singletonInstance either through a handle, or some other method?

Now that there have been a few comments and questions, I can explain a little more and clarify: what I have is basically a commonly shared resource (my singletonInstance.dll). Say appA needs that singletonInstance, if it isn't yet instanced, it will instance it. Then appB is started, and it needs a reference to the singletonInstance. That is the scenario.

Comment: You're working in .NET. Anything provided by the framework is cross-platform, for your purposes.

Comment: I'm wondering *why* you would want to do this.

Comment: The name "singletonInstance" is a code smell to me.

Comment: I was under the impression that using NamedPipes (DllImport from kernel32) would not be platform independent...

Comment: What behavior are you expecting from your "singleton" DLL? That instances of classes defined in that DLL are shared between different processes linked to it?

Comment: I am looking at the options I have of being able to find an instance of "MySharedDll" (whether networked, or local)...I have a range of applications that need to share the instance.

Comment: Named piped are supported in the .Net framework itself, you shouldn't need to use DllImport (probably bad if you do as you may not setup things like 'Dispose' correctly, better to use what has been provided and probably a lot better tested). Also, named pipes is an idea taken from unix, and thus, similar constructs are available on all major operating systems (windows/mac/*nix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you should manage the instance on a server and have the other applications talk to the server instead of the object itself.  Web services is the first thing that comes to mind but I don't know enough about your problem.

Comment: I had thought that Remoting (see my answer below) would be the answer. But this is really the best way to start out. We are looking at our options, including Tcp Sockets and implementing protobuf-net.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can comunicate through named pipes and when they're no available you can go to sockets, but it depends on what actually your "singleton" is going to do. Is it some kind of shared cache? Or what?

Will separate applications and "singleton" run on same machine or in network? Anyways socket's approach is good if you want to control low level implementation or you can go to webservices with some overhead or use remoting.

Comment: What I am working with now is using processes/application domains to "find" the instance of the .dll, then MarshalByRefObject - objtain my reference through the InstanceAndUnwrap() function. We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer up an answer - Runtime.Remoting.Channels. I had a common data object (the 'singletonInstance') inherit MarshaByRefObject. This gives us exactly what we want, plus we are making it capable of some networking features. Right now, this really acting like a service. The TcpChannel 'Server' is actually part of the .dll where the common data object is. This is mostly just for testing, experimental implementation, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're better off implementing whatever needs to be shared as a service.

You can connect to the service in a variety of ways that you choose to expose / implement / allow. Web Services, WCF, Named Pipes or raw sockets, etc. Choose whatever works best for you.

The service itself can then manage it's internal state appropriately (singleton anti-patterns or otherwise, it's irrelevant).

Think about how Sql Server is architected. It's not sharing the same dll instance across processes and memory boundaries, nor is it using heavy clients.

Comment: @Robert: Right...the CommonDataObject really sets up a 'common' instance where users have individual application workspaces, or even workgroup workspaces for collaborative efforts. This is also an attempt to create a platform independent solution and provide us with the capability to implement our custom security features.